# stretch the last li in horizontal menu till end of menu

Tags: css

As in the title - I want to stretch the last li tag in horizontal menu till end of menu. Here is my code:

```
#menu{width:600px; height:50px; background-color:#666; }
ul{padding:0; margin:0;}
ul li{list-style:none; height:20px;}
li{
float:left;
background-color:#999;
display:block;
padding:10px;
border-right-style:solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #000;} 



<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="last"></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Why not just put the background colour on the UL or the #menu instead?

Comment: Semantically speaking, having an empty element like your list item is a very poor practice.  There are clearfix methods that don't involve extra markup: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: so how will be this clearfix used here? I can't figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just simply add

```
.last { 
    float: none;
}
```

and the complete thing will be as wide as it can because it's display is set to block.

Alternately you could just set the background-color of the ul.

**UPDATE**

The solution doesn't work perfectly, as it does span the li over the complete ul.

The fix is actually pretty simple:

```
.last {
    float: none;
    overflow: hidden;/* Add this */
}
```

See updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BsrLD/8/

Comment: sorry I tested it but the last li is spreading all over the menu and the is visible under other li tags. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/BsrLD/ - there is a red background between the links blocks

Answer (score 2):

You can take off the float on the last li and it gives the result i think you want.
`.last{float:none}`

You can see in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NQq7B/)

Comment: I tested it but the last li is spreading all over the menu and the is visible under other li tags. Check this: jsfiddle.net/BsrLD - there is a red background between the links blocks.

Comment: @LjuboValevski You can remove the floats and use `display: inline-block`. Then hardcore a width onto the last li otherwise the width will be the length of the content inside it. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BsrLD/1/)

Comment: but in your case the .last is with fixed width - it should be flexible.

Comment: @LjuboValevski you can use `.last{width: 65%;}` and it should be the same on all resolutions. Using % gives u a relative width

Comment: no it does not work in that way. the links before the last <li> may vary too - in the example they are 3 but they could be 1,2,... 6

Comment: @LjuboValevski I don't know how to give it a dynamic width that changes on the fly. But you can still give it a width with % after u added all the li elements. Unless it will be updating the amount of li frequently.