# Horizontal menu not stretching to full width on hover in certain browsers

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a horizontal menu that is made up of a series of ul's and li's. The submenus look great so I don't need to do anything with those. The primary ul looks great until you hover over the far right li.

When doing that, it looks good in Safari but the hover comes about 2 pixels short of the background on the ul in Firefox and IE and even more in Chrome. I have tried adjusting the padding to make it look good in Firefox and IE but then you still have the same issue in Chrome and in Safari, that far right li breaks down to a new line. Of course, adjusting it to look good in Chrome makes all the other browsers break to a new line. This site is using Wordpress which creates the menu dynamically so I can only change the CSS. Here is the basic idea for the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #header {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 980px;
    }
    ul li {
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 21px;
    }
    #header .main-nav #menu-main-navigation {
        background: #169BAC;
        width: 100%
    }
    #header .main-nav > div ul {
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    #header .main-nav > div ul li ul{
        top: 43px;
    }
    #header .main-nav .menu-div>ul>li {
        padding: 5px 14px;
        float: left;
        border-right: solid 1px #54AEC2;
    }
    #header .main-nav .menu-div  ul li:hover {
        background: #2A588D;
    }
    #header .main-nav .menu-div>ul>li:first-child {
        padding-top: 9px;
        height: 28px;
    }
    #header .main-nav .menu-div>ul>li:last-child {
        padding: 5px 26px;
        border-right: none;
    }
    #header .main-nav .menu-div>ul>li a{
        line-height: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 0px 13px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <div class="menu-div">
                <ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-275"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-310"><a href="#">For New<br />Patients</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-376"><a href="#">Cleanings &#038;<br />Prevention</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-381"><a href="#">General<br />Dentistry</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-453"><a href="#">Restore Your<br />Smile</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-462"><a href="#">Dental Anxiety &#038;<br />Sedation Options</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-463"><a href="#">Dentistry For<br />Kids</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-464"><a href="#">Insurance &#038;<br />Payment Options</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

You can see the site at http://riverbend.caswellwebcreations.com.

Thank you for any help that you can give me on this.

Comment: You should post the minimum code required to replicate the problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [ask]

Comment: It took some doing but I was able to create a code sample that I could include in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the li elements is being defined by their padding and the font-size (and padding) of the a elements inside them. The font propertys are not uniform between browsers, some browsers put text bigger or smaller than others. That seems to be the problem.

If you want to stretch the li elements "cross-browser" you should define the width of the li elements via css like this:

```
#menu-item-275{
    width: 64px;
    }
#menu-item-310{
    width: 77px;
    }
#menu-item-376{
    width: 96px;
    }
#menu-item-381{
    width: 82px;
    }
#menu-item-453{
    width: 104px;
    }
#menu-item-462{
    width: 131px;
    }
#menu-item-463{
    width: 105px;
    }
#menu-item-464{
    width: 132px;
    }
```

If you sum the width of each li item (plus padding and border) you get the width of the menu container: 980px. And the browsers will take that width to render the li's.

I hope this works!

**UPDATE**

Just found another (and more easy) solution!: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361778/3762078

```
#header .main-nav .menu-div>ul>li:last-child {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-right: none;
    float: none; /* ADD THIS */
    overflow: hidden; /* AND THIS */
    }
```

1. 'float: none'. Forces last li element to be as wide as it can (the
   default block element's behavior).
2. 'overflow: hidden'. Prevents the last li element to stretch to ul's full width.

Although this doesn't prevent the width changes to all li elements on every browser, hence making the last li's width be thinner or wider (and sometimes expanding that li's height), is a nice solution.

Comment: I had to make some adjustments because it looked like crap in IE but the concept and explanation of the problem were great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks! If you are interested i found another solution. Read the UPDATE!